# Remove all style tages from html using c# using regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace

I have this example html - `string html="<span id="x" style="color:#000000;">aaaaa</span>"`
I am trying this to get html without the style:

> `string clean = Regex.Replace(html, "style=\\?\"[^\"]*\\?\"", "");`

the regex should also target `<span id="x" style=\"color:#000000;\">aaaaa</span>`
In this case the result inside `clean` is the same as `html`
Any thought?

Comment: Rather than regex can you use HTML parser, remove the styling, and then stream it?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454